# CMake Linking Path

Tags: c++, opencv, hyperlink, cmake

I'm trying to link a program to OpenCV libraries, which are located in: /usr/local/lib

So in the CMakeLists.txt I put:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myprogram 
    opencv_core 
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_highgui
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_objdetect
)
```

And building proceed, but if I do:

```
ldd myprogram
```

I'm getting:

```
...
libopencv_core.so.2.4 => not found
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 => not found
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 => not found
libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4 => not found
```

so in order to be able to run it I must add each time /usr/local/lib to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I've replaced the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES config to this one:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myprogram ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

and now it's linking the libraries correctly.. but all of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your environment variables are set properly and then use these lines in your CMakeList file.

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( myProject ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: I did it, and it finds the package (no cake errors and build/linkg succeeds) but after the binary it's not actually linked.. maybe /usr/local/lib is in CMake library path but not in system's

Comment: Could you check if CMake is indeed linking to the correct folder..? This is very unusual, to be honest.

Comment: I added a MESSAGE("OpenCV_LIBS: ${OpenCV_LIBS}") and it outputs:
 debug;/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so;...

Comment: Any luck..? I am not able to replicate your error on my machine.. You are trying to link to OpenCV 2.4, right..? Can you give me more details about your OS and system..? Perhaps using a newer OpenCV version would do the trick.

Comment: Well the update is: using TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( myProject ${OpenCV_LIBS} ) it works, but links all the libraries. If I want to link only a subset of them it doesn't work. With BOOST I'm not having this kind of problem, maybe in find_package i should specify only needed modules

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your dynamic library loader to include those directories too. Add the path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` file or create a `.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory

Comment: ok, but I can't understand why at building/linking time everything goes fine, and not after.

Comment: My ld.so.conf file contains: 
/usr/X11R6/lib64/Xaw3d
/usr/X11R6/lib64
/usr/lib64/Xaw3d
/usr/X11R6/lib/Xaw3d
/usr/X11R6/lib
/usr/lib/Xaw3d
/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/lib
/usr/local/lib
/opt/kde3/lib
/lib64
/lib
/usr/lib64
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib64
/usr/local/lib

and result is the same